# Google Analytics Embed API gapi.analytics.auth.isAuthorized() always returns false

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-api

I am experimenting with embedding Google Analytics in my CMS. I want to check whether the user is authorized and if they are, I will display a 'sign out' button so that they can sign out and then sign in with a different Google account.

I have the sign out button working but I don't want it displayed unless the user is signed in.

According to the docs, this should work:
    gapi.analytics.auth.isAuthorized()

But when I log that to the console it always returns false.

Here's a bit more of my code:

```
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

        /**
         * Authorize the user immediately if the user has already granted access.
         * If no access has been created, render an authorize button inside the
         * element with the ID "embed-api-auth-container".
         */
        gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
            container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
            clientid: 'XXXXX'
        });

        console.log(gapi.analytics.auth.isAuthorized());
```

Please can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late with the answer but maybe will help someone.

Google analytics api uses OAuth 2.0 for authorization, and 
`gapi.analytics.auth.isAuthorized()` from your code always returns false because there is no currently authorized users.

You can easly check if there's authorized users:

```
var isAuthorized = gapi.analytics.auth.isAuthorized();

if(isAuthorized == true) {
  // display sign out button
}else {
  // display sign in button
}
```

If you already have an access token, you can include it authorize, and user will be signed in automatically:

```
gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
    clientid: 'XXXXX',
    serverAuth: {
       access_token: 'XXXXX'
    }
});
```

and run check:

```
var isAuthorized = gapi.analytics.auth.isAuthorized();

if(isAuthorized == true) {
  // display sign out button
}else {
  // display sign in button
}
```